# how to check URLSessionDataTask response data is Array or dictionary?

Tags: swift, nsurlsession

Every time I get an error for:

> jsonError::Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 1." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 1.}

```
let dataTask: URLSessionDataTask = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest as URLRequest) { (data:Data?, response:URLResponse?,error: Error?) in
    if((error) != nil){
        completionHandler(false, nil, error)
    }
    else{
        do {
            let responseData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments)

            if responseData is Dictionary<String, Any>{
                print("dictionary type")
            }
            else if responseData is Array<Any>{
                print("array type")
            }
        }
        catch let jsonError {
            print("jsonError::\(jsonError)")
            completionHandler(false, nil, jsonError)
        }

    }


}

dataTask.resume();
```

Please suggest. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like the data isn't valid JSON, at all. Try logging the data and/or the data converted to a string.

Comment: @KenThomases response string generated response with html page tags. 
any alternative?
in objective-c tried with 

id response = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&jsonError];
    
    NSDictionary * jsonDictionary = [NSDictionary new];
    
    if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        jsonDictionary = response;
    }
    else{
        jsonDictionary = [response lastObject];
    }

work fine getting problem in swift.

Comment: Have you tried like this:-  if let responseData = responseData as? [[String:Any]] { }

Comment: @HussainShabbir

let responseData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments)

not parse response value in responseData and goes to catch block 

so i am not able to compare this condition 

 if let responseData = responseData as? [[String:Any]] { }

Answer (score 0):

The error (points to you for actually examining the error, it is amazing how many people ask questions without doing this) tells you that the data that you received isn't valid JSON at all.

You say that you are receiving a response with html tags. That means that either the server code is broken, or you use an incorrect URL or incorrect parameters. Many servers will return JSON if you ask them to return JSON, and HTML otherwise, so you just have to figure out how to ask correctly. (Often you can just type variations of the URL into your browser to find out).

I noticed that you used .allowFragments. This option allows the parser to parse not only dictionaries and arrays, but also "fragments", that is a string, number, boolean value or null. Obviously in these cases you won't get a dictionary or array, so don't use this option unless you expect a fragment and know how to handle it.

It seems that you expect either a dictionary, or an array containing a single dictionary. (I'd ask first whether an empty array or an array containing more than one dictionary is acceptable, if yes then you need to change the code). I'd assume that you want to report an error in all error cases. I'd write the dataTask completion handler like this (up to you to make it compile)

```
guard error == nil else { 
    handle error
    return
}

guard data != nil else else { 
    handle error
    return
}

guard let parsed = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject (...) else { 
    handle error
    return
}

if let dict = parsed as? [String: Any] {
    handle result dict
    return 
}

guard let array = parsed as? [Any] else { 
    handle error
    return
}

guard array.count == 1 else { 
    handle error
    return
}

if let dict = array [0] as? [String: Any] {
    handle result dict
} else {
    handle error 
}
```

Comment: the HTML response is generate when data converted to string.

tried the requested POST url on POSTMAN it generate the response with 
non JSON format like this [{"Error":true,"Error_Message":"No Data Available"}]

how can i parse this ?